# C++ Allegro 5.0.8 - al_load_bitmap() returning NULL on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, allegro

I'm developing a game in Allegro 5.0.8, and everything was going well, until i tried compiling  it and running it on Linux (Mint 14)...so i did sime tests;

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    al_init();
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *screen = al_create_display(800, 600);
    al_init_image_addon();

    ALLEGRO_PATH *path = al_get_standard_path(ALLEGRO_RESOURCES_PATH);
    al_set_path_filename(path, "players.png");
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *img = al_load_bitmap(al_path_cstr(path, '/'));

    if (img == NULL)
        std::cout << al_path_cstr(path, '/') << std::endl;

    al_draw_bitmap(img, 0, 0, 0);
    al_flip_display();

    while (true){}
    return 0;
}
```

this example compiles just fine, but the line

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *img = al_load_bitmap(al_path_cstr(path, '/'));
```

returns **NULL**. On the other hand, the line

```
std::cout << al_path_cstr(path, '/') << std::endl;
```

prints the exact absolute path of the image.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: PNG files are supported via external libraries, do you have e.g. `libpng` installed?

Comment: i have libpng12-0 ..but not libpng12-dev...should i install that too??

Comment: Yes you probably need that too, and to link with `libpng` (i.e. `-lpng`) as well.

Comment: i tried, and it still returns NULL...on the other hand i tried with a bmp, and it works...so, what am i doing wrong?? ...to compile i use: **g++ *.cpp -o test -lpng12 `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_image-5.0`** ...i tried also -libpng

Comment: You should check what error you get, either with [`allegro_error`](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/4/api/using-allegro/allegro_error) or with [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno).

Comment: i don't really know how to use those, but when the program crashes i get **bitmap.c:315: al_draw_tinted_bitmap: Assertion `bitmap' failed.**

Comment: `allegro_error` is a string you can print out directly, while `errno` is an integer, but you can use the [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) function to get a string from that (e.g. `strerror(errno)`).

Comment: so, where should i check for the error? ...because on the line **al_draw_bitmap(img, 0, 0, 0);** the program crashes, because of img being NULL

Comment: It crashes because you pass a `NULL` pointer to the function. If the pointer is `NULL` don't call the function. You already check for error, in the `if` statement, in there _also_ print out the possible error messages and then exit the program (or do something else). But whatever you do, do not use a `NULL` pointer except to check if it's `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

> i have libpng12-0 ..but not libpng12-dev...should i install that too??

After you install libpng12-dev, you'll need to rebuild Allegro. The output of cmake tells you whether or not PNG is supported.

Once you rebuild Allegro with PNG support, it will work assuming your PNG file is not too big to load onto your video card.